# android button start activity error

Tags: android

I use this code to start activity when press the imagebutton

```
     import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickListener listnr=new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, FlashActivity.class);
                 startActivity(i);
            }
      };
      Button imageButton1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
      imageButton1.setOnClickListener(listnr);
}
}
```

it crash can anyone tell me the error in this code

The Error
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.flash/com.app.flash.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at com.app.flash.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
12-04 14:30:02.506: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    ... 11 more

Comment: whenever u post a code that crashes, it is recommended u also post the error stack trace, so the problem can be detected more easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this it will solve your problem

```
 Intent i= new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, UpcomingActivity.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

Don't forget to define your class in manifest file.

For Ex:

```
Button imageButton1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent i= new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, UpcomingActivity.class);
     startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Make sure that in xml file you have included button not imageButton. If image Button in xml file then you need as undermentioned :

```
ImageButton imageButton1 =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

Comment: i try this but i face the same problem

  OnClickListener listnr=new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, FlashActivity.class);
           startActivity(i);
         }
   };
   Button imageButton1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
   imageButton1.setOnClickListener(listnr);
}

Answer (score 1):

start Activity on Button Click as:

```
 OnClickListener listnr=new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent i= new Intent(v.getContext(),FlashActivity.class);
              startActivity(i);
        }
  };
```

and also make sure you have declared `FlashActivity` Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 1):

```
              OnClickListener=new OnClickListener()
              {
               @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent i= new Intent(context,classname);
                 startActivity(i);
     }
 };
   Button imageButton1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
   imageButton1.setOnClickListener(listnr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define this variable in your activity
    public Context context ;

and in your on Create before the listener write:
    context=this

and change startactivity(i) with context.startActivity(i)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try his way:

```
OnClickListener listnr=new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

              startActivity(new Intent("currentActivity.this, FlashActivity.class"));
        }
  };
  Button imageButton1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
  imageButton1.setOnClickListener(listnr);
```

Comment: 12-04 14:06:40.504: E/AndroidRuntime(25649):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
12-04 14:06:40.504: E/AndroidRuntime(25649):  ... 11 more